# Cannot read property ‘selected’ of null

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, tabs

On first login of the app I get an error 'Cannot read property ‘selected’ of null'.  I have to close the app then re-open for the tabs to work.

In app.component I have

```
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
  if(!user){
    this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    unsubscribe();
  } else {
    this.rootPage = TabsPage;
    unsubscribe();
  }
});
```

If I close the app then re-open it works fine, but on initial login it goes to the 'Settings' page as opposed to the index(0) page.  If I close then re-open it will go to index(0) page and everything works fine.

Actual code causing the error from the tabPage index 2.  `skipAddingInfo(){
      this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);
    }` .     This code is being executed from from the 3rd page in the tab page index...so index(2).

Comment: Please share the code where the error is originating from. There is no `selected` property being used in the code shared. If the error is not originating from your code, then provide the call stack.

Comment: This is the actual code causing the error:        skipAddingInfo(){
      this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);
    }